# Is there a tool in Python to create text tables like Powershell?

Tags: python, console

Whenever PowerShell displays its objects, it formats them in a nice pretty manner in the monospaced console, e.g.:

```
> ps

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
    101       5     1284       3656    32     0.03   3876 alg
    257       7     4856      10228    69     0.67    872 asghost
    101       4     3080       4696    38     0.36   1744 atiptaxx
    179       7     5568       7008    54     0.22    716 BTSTAC~1
...
```

Is there a similar library in Python or do I get to make one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think python [texttable](https://web.archive.org/web/20151013083141/http://foutaise.org:80/code/texttable/) module does exactly what you were looking for.

[For further information.](https://oneau.wordpress.com/2010/05/30/simple-formatted-tables-in-python-with-texttable/)

Comment: That looks almost like a good solution. Do you know whether it's possible to produce tables in Markdown-like style? E.g. http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Answer (score 4):

#### pprint — Data pretty printer

There is a [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) module which does a little bit of that. It's not as nice as your example but it does at least try to print 2-D and recursive data structures more intelligently than `str()`.

> The pprint module provides a capability to “pretty-print” arbitrary Python data structures in a form which can be used as input to the interpreter. If the formatted structures include objects which are not fundamental Python types, the representation may not be loadable. This may be the case if objects such as files, sockets, classes, or instances are included, as well as many other built-in objects which are not representable as Python constants.

#### numpy — Scientific computing

Then there is [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) module which is targeted at mathematic and scientific computing, but is also pretty darn good at displaying matrices:

```
>>> from numpy import arange
>>> b = arange(12).reshape(4,3)  # 2d array
>>> print b
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this for my self; This is not exactly what is asked in the question, but it may help someone anyway :)

Usage:

```py
table(
    [
        ['Title A', 'Title B', 'Title C'],
        ['Value A', 'Value B', 'Value C'],
        ['101', '102', '103'],
        ['1000', '2000', '1234567890123456'],
        ['Text A', 'Text B', 'Text C']
    ]
)
```

I used **rich** for colors; but you can remove it.

Output:

[image]

Source code:

```py
from rich import print

TBL_TOP = ['┌', '─', '┬', '┐']
TBL_MID = ['├', '─', '┼', '┤']
TBL_BTM = ['└', '─', '┴', '┘']
TBL_TXT = ['│', ' ', '│', '│']
TBL_TTL = ['╞', '═', '╪', '╡']


def word(word, size, color):
    l = len(word)
    if l > size:
        return word[0:size] if l <= 3 else word[0:size-3]+'...'
    space = size-l
    return f'[{color}]'+word+(space*' ')+'[/]'


def draw(cols, w, num=' ', type=TBL_TOP, input=None, color='green'):
    left, center, middle, right = type[:4]
    print(f'{num} {left}', end='')
    for col in range(0, cols):
        print(center*w if type !=
              TBL_TXT else word(input[col], w, color), end='')
        print(middle, end='') if col < cols-1 else print(right)


def table(arr, w=15):
    rows, cols = len(arr), len(arr[0])
    draw(cols, w)
    draw(cols, w, type=TBL_TXT, input=arr[0], color='yellow')
    for r in range(1, rows):
        draw(cols, w, type=TBL_TTL if r == 1 else TBL_MID)
        draw(cols, w, type=TBL_TXT, num=r, input=arr[r])
        if r == rows-1:
            draw(cols, w, type=TBL_BTM)
    pass
```